# Setting a User Agent in scrape-it

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, user-agent

I'm using [scrape-it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scrape-it) in my node.js scraping tool (for identifying proper keyword usage) but being identified as a bot by some websites and not getting any content. Is there a way to configure a known [user agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) header for the GET request to bypass the block?

Answer (score 3):

You can set the headers, including User-agent, by passing an options object to scrape-it:

```
scrapeIt({
    url: "http://example.com"
  , headers: { "User-agent": "known-user-agent-of-choice" }
},
{
  // some scrapeHTML options ...
})
.then(
 // some code ...
);
```